# Regex Match Statement

Tags: c#, regex

I have following statement:

```
(( {  dbo.Document.MimeType_ID in (select ID from MimeType where Name ='PDF')}   Or  {  dbo.WorkflowItem.CurrentStateName not like 'On_Hold%'} )  And ( {  dbo.DocumentMetaData.Field_ID=74 And  dbo.DocumentMetaData.FieldValue Not like '%test%'}   And  {  dbo.Document.FileName='karan'} ))
```

I want to 4 statements between {}

eg

```
dbo.Document.MimeType_ID in (select ID from MimeType where Name ='PDF')
dbo.WorkflowItem.CurrentStateName not like 'On_Hold%'
dbo.DocumentMetaData.Field_ID=74 And  dbo.DocumentMetaData.FieldValue Not like '%test%'
dbo.Document.FileName='karan'
```

Comment: is there nested pattern? Also I will suggest you to use parser

Comment: No it is not nested pattern, actually its advance search formula, now I want to restore search, my simple requirement is how to get all statements between {}

Comment: is https://regex101.com/r/tQ9bY6/2 good?

Comment: Yes worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work (if there is no nested pattern)

```
\{\s*([^}]+)\s*\}
```

*C# Code*

```
string input = "(( {  dbo.Document.MimeType_ID in (select ID from MimeType where Name ='PDF')}   Or  {  dbo.WorkflowItem.CurrentStateName not like 'On_Hold%'} )  And ( {  dbo.DocumentMetaData.Field_ID=74 And  dbo.DocumentMetaData.FieldValue Not like '%test%'}   And  {  dbo.Document.FileName='karan'} ))";
string pattern = "\\{\\s*([^}]+)\\s*\\}";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = rgx.Match(input);

while (match.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
 }
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/26RB80)**